# Hybrid event with cap for the in-person space: setup suggestions?

Tags: civievent, scheduled-reminders

We are setting up a "hybrid" event that has in-person cap at 20 participants due to the room size (with a waitlist), plus an unlimited (ideally no waitlist) Zoom option. We typically use scheduled reminders (to remind participants of the time, location and encourage them to cancel if they won't make it) one week and 3 days before events.

The only way I can think to do this is with two separate events with their own registration links, like "try this first and if it's full then click this link to register for the zoom", + sending the zoom link to those on waitlist status for the in-person...

Is there a better way to set this up than as two separate events? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use a Price Set for your event, then you can put a cap on one option

Does that give what you need?

[image]

Comment: Hm- maybe, thanks for the idea! We would like to have separate scheduled reminders, so that zoom people don't think it's an option for them show up in person. And so that in-person people actually show up, instead of just saying 5 minutes beforehand ahhhhhh I'll just zoom it's easier. Can price sets do this? Or... is there a price set token that can be set confirmation emails, and be set in scheduled reminders, that could clarify things for them? Thanks!

Comment: I expect you could include some Smarty if/else based on whether the line item is present or not. sorry can't spell out the steps